# What to blame? PHP/Apache or Chrome or Magento?

Tags: php, apache, magento

This is as very odd problem folks.. it effects only chrome, and only pages served in PHP.

I made a page which is just pure html being served with the same assets in the same dir as the handled page just because I was not sure what to do about the situation:

http://www.sublimewellness.ca/store/debug.html

www.sublimewellness.ca/store/
[image: issue on chrome response (when it fails).]
The page works just fine on other browsers but fails on chrome.

You will notice the page does not load on chrome (you can see the white screen and the html dump though).

If you get no response, its probably because magento is a beast and other stack exchange people are hitting it.

Here are the request headers..

```
GET /store/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.sublimewellness.ca
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cookie: frontend=47oojlnfi9aji3c85e3as98d63

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2013 08:01:43 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: frontend=47oojlnfi9aji3c85e3as98d63; expires=Tue, 10-Sep-2013 09:01:45 GMT; path=/store; domain=www.sublimewellness.ca; httponly
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

What to blame? I dont think its javascript, or the page dump html that is causing a random issue as the html page indicates its not a problem.

I dont think its PHP?
Its clearly not mysql.

Im putting my hands towards some sort of apache header.

I dont really want to just throw out other project specific code unless requested. Please let me know what you feel you need to know or what you would look for first and I will investigate and post what you need.

Should note that on rare occasion the page does load correctly in chrome!

Comment: loads fine here on chrome Version 29.0.1547.66 m

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this on the /store/ url (/store/debug.html works fine 100%)  Not quite sure why, the error it gives is pretty non-descript.

Comment: try re-installing/updating chrome

Comment: screwing with the htaccess file considerably and removing the complications seems to have solved the problem.. why and how I frankly do not know.

Comment: I get the same issue on my website too, only sometimes though, and only on Chrome